# Is using the const keyword always efficient in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, memory, constants

When creating a flutter app in the dart language, a hint message is given to attach a `const` keyword in front of `SizedBox`.

It is understood that attaching the `const` keyword increases execution speed by not performing unnecessary calculations at runtime and saves memory by not creating the same object twice.

Then, I wondered if `SizedBox` was not used from the start of the app to the end of the app, was it using unnecessary memory at compile time?

Also, what I'm still confused about is that memory is allocated at **compile time** when the `const` keyword is added, does that mean memory is allocated when the app is installed?

Does that mean it is stored in the **internal memory**?

On the other hand, what is calculated at runtime and put in memory is put in **RAM**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the answer given by ThanhNguyen, you should **use const wherever possible because const tells the dart compiler that once a function or widget is run it will always remain the same and won't change**. The build method is called very often in flutter. So, when `build` method is called by the flutter framework, a widget which is declared by `const` keyword, allows flutter to shortcuit the build method and avoid doing most of the work again and again. Because the `build` method is called whenever the state of widget is changed, `build` method is called many times in the same widget.

For ex:
When creating a container, with a radius

```
Container(
   decoration: const BoxDecoration(
       radius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
   ),
)
```

**When flutter framework builds this container, the const keyword when defining decoration of container helps fluter know that the decoration of container hasn't changed, and it doesn't have to clip the container again as the decoration is constant. This causes build method to execute fast.**

To answer your second question:
**No, it is not stored in your internal memory**. Compile time means when the app is opened, dart compiler compiles the project into native code, and the variable defined by const keyword is saved during compiling and there is no need of compiling the value of that variable again when running the app.

Flutter Documentation tells about more performance optimizations that can be done. See here: [Performance Best Practices](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/best-practices#minimize-expensive-operations)

Comment: If so, if there are a lot of variables defined with the const keyword, could the initial opening time of the app slow down?

Comment: No, the initial opening time will be the same as normal opening time.

Comment: It like all variables are generated during compile time, but const is type of flag for flutter to rebuilt the same thing again

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion, you use const keyword before some widget when parent of this widget rebuild this widget not rebuild again. You can try to wrap two stateful widget (A and B, A is parent widget of B) and call setState function, widget B will not run into build again! So when screen render again, if widgets have const keyword before, this don't rebuild again, it's better for performance!